# magento1.7 apache2.x and mod_pagespeed

Tags: magento-1.7, performance

Anybody konw how magento1.7 behave with mod_pagespeed apache module to increase performance of website?

Comment: this was already asked on stackoverflow alltough it was probably an older Magento the same thing will still apply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105441/mod-pagespeed-magento. If you want to up your performance i recommend looking at apc, Redis and Memcached.

Comment: its quite old discussion. may be mod_pagespeed was in its beta version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are running Pagespeed for multiple customers. Those customers are either running 1.12 or 1.13 Enterprise. When properly setup we have big improvements regarding the start of rendering the page (http://www.webpagetest.org/ is a great tools to see before/after numbers on that aspect).

We only ran into one small problem in the admin: Pagespeed will add a script tag to each page, so when you edit content in the admin via a wysiwyg popup. the popup will contain that script tag. It also looks like not all community modules will work properly in the admin. We fix this to prevent Pagespeed optimisations for the admin. We always run the admin on a separate subdomain (for example admin..

Note that when you run a cluster environment, it's best to setup Pagespeed to use memcache as it's caching backend. We created a additional cache option on Magento's Cache Management page to be able to easily flush that memcache pool from the backend.

We currently run the following filters: combine_css, combine_js, rewrite_css, rewrite_js, defer_js and a few others.

So far we did not ran into any problems on the frontend. We are running Pagespeed now for several months.